# iterate over array to find int over 10 and add those two digits together

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration

Trying to iterate over and array and for any digit 10 or higher, split those digits and add them together for instance: `10 > "1" "0" > 1`.

I am able to iterate through the array and achieve that. however, it returns `nil` instead of the `digits < 9`.

```
def over_ten_sum
  #splits the numbers over 10 into seperate digit and sums them
  square_odd.map do |num|
    if num > 9
      num.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map { |num_1, num_2| num_1.to_i + num_2.to_i }
    end
  end
end
```

With a value of `[6, 4, 10, 2, 14, 7, 8, 4, 6, 7, 18, 4]` it returns:

```
=> [nil, nil, [1], nil, [5], nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, [9], nil]
```

I am trying to have the output be 
`[6, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 6, 7, 9, 4]`

Just not seeing the disconnect here. Thank you in advance for any insights.

Comment: `...over_ten_sum...if num > 9...`. Hmmm. :-)

Comment: There is no need for special casing numbers < 10: The sum of digits of a single-digit number is the same as the number. Just sum the digits of all numbers and get rid of the special case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `if`:

```
def over_ten_sum
  #splits the numbers over 10 into seperate digit and sums them
  square_odd.map do |num|
    num.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map { |num_1, num_2| num_1.to_i + num_2.to_i }
  end.flatten
end

#=> [6, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6, 7, 9, 4]
```

What was wrong? `if num > 9` left out every other number from being treated and nothing was returned, so you got `nil` each time. To make it clearer, check the following code:

```
def over_ten_sum
  #splits the numbers over 10 into seperate digit and sums them
  square_odd.map do |num|
    if num > 9
      num.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map { |num_1, num_2| num_1.to_i + num_2.to_i }
    else
      num
    end
  end.flatten
end

#=> [6, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 4, 6, 7, 9, 4]
```

As you can see, the result is the same, because `else` send `num` back as it is when it is not greater than 9.

Comment: You could `flatten` the result Gerry, to get the expected output. Well done.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Ohh, nice catch. I'll edit. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, thank you @Gerry! I didn't even think of `flatten` Im on my way to read the doc on that now. I wish my vote for your answer would count, but alas, I'm less than 15 rep:P Thank you again sir!

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you were to write

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |n| }
  #=> [nil, nil, nil]
```

An array of `nil`s is returned because `map` returns `nil` for `n` if `n` is not assigned a value in the block. Similarly,

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |n| 2*n if n > 1 }
  #=> [nil, 4, 6]
```

which is very similar to the problem with the OP's code. If one doesn't want `nil`s in the array returned one simply needs to map each element of the array into a non-nil value:

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |n| n > 1 ? 2*n : n }
  #=> [1, 4, 6]
```

Now let's look at the line

```
num.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map { |num_1, num_2| num_1.to_i + num_2.to_i }
```

If `num = 34`, this returns `[7]`, which, except for the fact that `7` is in an array, is correct. On the other hand, if `num = 134` the expression returns `[4, 4]` (i.e., `[1+3, 4]`), which I don't expect is what is wanted. If, however, the numbers always have two digits, the above expression is the same as:

```
num[0].to_i + num[1].to_i
```

which is much simpler.<sup>1</sup> To make it more general you need to write something like the following<sup>2</sup>:

```
def over_nine_sum(arr)
  arr.map { |n| n > 9 ? n.to_s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,s| t + s.to_i } : n }
end

over_nine_sum [12, 5, 71, 3]
  #=> [3, 5, 8, 3]
```

See [Enumerable#reduce](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`).

@JörgWMittag noted (see comment) that the sum of the digits of a single-digit number (`0-9`) is the same as the number itself, so there is no need to treat those numbers differently. We may therefore write

```
def sum_digits(arr)
  arr.map { |n| n.to_s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,s| t + s.to_i } }
end

sum_digits [12, 5, 71, 3]
  #=> [3, 5, 8, 3]
```

As @steenslag's suggested in a comment, this can be simplified to

```
def sum_digits(arr)
  arr.map { |n| n.digits.sum }
end
```

which uses the methods [Integer#digits](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) and [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) (both new in Ruby v2.4).

Consider the steps (for the first version of `sum_digits` above) when `n = 34`:

```
n.to_s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,s| t + s.to_i }
  #=> 34.to_s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,s| t + s.to_i }
  #=> "34".each_char.reduce(0) { |t,s| t + s.to_i }
```

Now `reduce` initializes the block variable `t` (the "memo", which is returned) to zero and passes the first digit of `"34"` to the block and assigns it to the block variable `s`:

```
t = 0
s = "3"
```

The block calculation is:

```
t + s.to_i
  #=> 0 + "3".to_i
  #=> 3
```

which is the updated value of `t`. Next,

```
s = "4"
t + s.to_i
  #=> 3 + "4".to_i
  #=> 3 + 4
  #=> 7
```

<sup>1. Another problem is that if `square_odd` is a local variable, Ruby will raise an "undefined variable or method" exception when it evaluates it.</sup>

<sup>2. `n.to_s.each_char.reduce(0)...` is preferable to `n.to_s.chars.reduce(0)...` because `chars` returns a temporary array whereas `each_char` returns an enumerator.</sup>

Comment: Ruby 2.4 also introduced `Integer#digits`.

Comment: @steenslag, thanks, good suggestion. I wasn't aware of that method. I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: There is no need for special casing numbers < 10: The sum of digits of a single-digit number is the same as the number. Just sum the digits of all numbers and get rid of the special case: `arr.map {|n| n.digits.sum }` or if you don't mind two traversals `arr.map(&:digits).map(&:sum)`.